# Filtering Matrix in R

Tags: r

I have two data, one logical (`selected`):

```
  YPR163C   YPR164W   YPR165W   YPR166C   YPR167C   YPR168W   YPR169W   YPR170C 
    FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE 
  YPR171W   YPR172W   YPR173C   YPR174C   YPR175W   YPR176C   YPR177C   YPR178W 
    FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     TRUE      FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE 
  YPR179C   YPR180W   YPR181C   YPR182W   YPR183W   YPR184W   YPR185W   YPR186C 
    FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     TRUE      FALSE     FALSE     FALSE 
  YPR187W   YPR188C   YPR189W   YPR190C   YPR191W   YPR192W   YPR193C   YPR194C 
    FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE 
  YPR195C   YPR196W   YPR197C   YPR198W   YPR199C   YPR200C   YPR201W   YPR202W 
    FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE 
  YPR203W   YPR204W 
    FALSE     FALSE
```

and the other a matrix (`dataExpr`):

```
        cln3.1       cln3.2 clb2.2 clb2.1 alpha0 alpha7 alpha14 alpha21 alpha28
YAL001C   0.15 -0.006660232  -0.22   0.07  -0.15  -0.15   -0.21    0.17   -0.42
YAL002W  -0.07 -0.760000000  -0.12  -0.25  -0.11   0.10    0.01    0.06    0.04
YAL003W  -1.22 -0.270000000  -0.10   0.23  -0.14  -0.71    0.10   -0.32   -0.40
YAL004W  -0.09  1.200000000   0.16  -0.14  -0.02  -0.48   -0.11    0.12   -0.03
YAL005C  -0.60  1.010000000   0.24   0.65  -0.05  -0.53   -0.47   -0.06    0.11
YAL007C   0.65  1.390000000  -0.29  -0.54  -0.60  -0.45   -0.13    0.35   -0.01
```

I wanna filter out the rows that are FALSE in the logical data. I've tried different things such as:

```
esetSel <- dataExpr[selected, ]
```

but it does not work... Output:

```
 cln3.1 cln3.2 clb2.2 clb2.1 alpha0 alpha7 alpha14 alpha21 alpha28 alpha35
 alpha42 alpha49 alpha56 alpha63 alpha70 alpha77 alpha84 alpha91 alpha98 alpha105
 alpha112 alpha119 cdc15.10 cdc15.30 cdc15.50 cdc15.70 cdc15.80 cdc15.90
 cdc15.100 cdc15.110 cdc15.120 cdc15.130 cdc15.140 cdc15.150 cdc15.160 cdc15.170
 cdc15.180 cdc15.190 cdc15.200 cdc15.210 cdc15.220 cdc15.230 cdc15.240 cdc15.250
 cdc15.270 cdc15.290 cdc28.0 cdc28.10 cdc28.20 cdc28.30 cdc28.40 cdc28.50
 cdc28.60 cdc28.70 cdc28.80 cdc28.90 cdc28.100 cdc28.110 cdc28.120 cdc28.130
 cdc28.140 cdc28.150 cdc28.160 elu0 elu30 elu60 elu90 elu120 elu150 elu180 elu210
 elu240 elu270 elu300 elu330 elu360 elu390
```

Comment: Could you expand on what you mean by "it does not work"? What happens, exactly?

Comment: Your approach is methodologically sound, can you tell us what output are you getting? any errors? or the resulting matrix is not what you expect.

Comment: @TWL, one obvious thing is that the order of the keys is not the same in both items.

Comment: Please, does `all(rownames(dataExpr) %in% names(selected))` return TRUE or FALSE? I am asking because in your current example, none of the `rownames(dataExpr)` are found in `names(selected)`. Can you tell why it might be a problem?

Comment: @flodel, indeed, I am puzzled by the blank output, given the logical string contains TRUE values, the resulting matrix should contain rows that match with index of the TRUE values, ignoring the names. The order is another issue.

Comment: Oh sorry, I am stupid. I've just realized that I was testing it with data where all the values were FALSE. Now I tested it with another data set and it works perfectly. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Well now it all makes perfect sense! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the names of elements of `selected` correspond to the row names of `dataExpr`, then the following should work:

```
esetSel <- dataExpr[selected[row.names(dataExpr)], ]
```

It subsets (or reorders) `selected` such that it matches the order of row names of `dataExpr`, then subsets `dataExpr` by the resulting logical vector.